# NSManagedObjectContext's performBlock is unreachable

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have one background context in separate class:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)privateWriterContext
{
    if (!_privateWriterContext)
    {
        _privateWriterContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        _privateWriterContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    return _privateWriterContext;
}
```

And I want to get some data in my controller to update UI:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [CoreDataManager shared].privateWriterContext;

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [context performBlock:^{
        NSFetchRequest* req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[Z9Dashboard entityName]];
        Z9Dashboard* dashboard = [context executeFetchRequest:req error:nil].lastObject;
        weakSelf.gameEnabled = [dashboard.activePlates integerValue] >= 9;

        typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // code that uses strongSelf.gameEnabled for UI updates
        });
    }];
}
```

This works great on iOS8, but the code in `performBlock` sometimes is unreachable on iPad2 with iOS7. Even on simulator! Why? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "unreachable"?

Comment: @MartinR, I mean, if I put a breakpoint in the `NSFetchRequest* req = ...` string, or if I add `NSLog`, I neither stop on this string nor get the log message. And context is not nil.